# Show div only if specific other divs have been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery (this is my second attempt). I looked for answers via Google and StackOverflow and I have tried quite a few but have yet to figure out the last part of my problem. Any help or guidance is most appreciated.

What I want to do is have a bunch of images(apple, pumpkin, candle, etc) that when clicked, fade the image out and then cross off the image's name in a text list. Then, if you click on specific sets of those images they will show a div containing a deal.

*An example:* If you click on the images of apple, pear and pumpkin (in any order) a deal will show.
*Another example:* You click on the images of candle, apple, pumpkin and key(in any order) a deal will show.
Another example: You click on all image items(in any order) a deal shows.

I have the first part working (click on an image, it fades out and crosses its name off the list).

What I need help with is checking to see if certain combinations of images have been clicked and if so show the deal div.

I was thinking I could use index for this but I haven't been able to make it work. Maybe there is a better way? Thanks for any guidance.

Here is my test code so far ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/2QkXh/12/)):

HTML

```
    <div class="pic1">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/chudtsankov/chudtsankov1208/chudtsankov120800002/14670247-cartoon-red-apple.jpg" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic2">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://www.in.gov/visitindiana/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/pumpkin.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic3">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Candle_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic4">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://tasty-dishes.com/data_images/encyclopedia/pear/pear-06.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic5">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://free.clipartof.com/57-Free-Cartoon-Gray-Field-Mouse-Clipart-Illustration.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="pic6">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="http://images.wisegeek.com/brass-key.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="items">
    <p class="apple">Apple</p>
    <p class="pumpkin">Pumpkin</p>
    <p class="candle">Candle</p>
    <p class="pear">Pear</p>
    <p class="mouse">Mouse</p>
    <p class="key">Key</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someText">Reveal Deal #1 after finding apple, candle and mouse</div>
    <div class="deal1">This is deal box #1! You must have found apple, candle and mouse! WIN</div>
    <div class="someText">Reveal Deal #2 after finding key, pumpkin, pear and mouse!</div>
    <div class="deal2">This is deal box #2! You must have found key, pumpkin, pear and mouse!</div>
    <div class="someText">Reveal Deal #3 after finding ALL objects!</div>
    <div class="deal3">This is deal box #3! You must have ALL the items!</div>
    <div id="output"></div>`
```

CSS

```
.intro, .someText {
        color:#333;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .deal1, .deal2, .deal3 {
        font-size: 18px;
        color: red;
    }
```

Javascript: jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.deal1, .deal2, .deal3').hide();

    $('.pic1').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $('#items p.apple').wrap('<strike>');
        $(".pic1").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.pic2').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $("#items p.pumpkin").wrap("<strike>");
        $(".pic2").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.pic3').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $("#items p.candle").wrap("<strike>");
        $(".pic3").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.pic4').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $("#items p.pear").wrap("<strike>");
        $(".pic4").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.pic5').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $("#items p.mouse").wrap("<strike>");
        $(".pic5").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    $('.pic6').click(function () {
        $(this).data('clicked');
        $("#items p.key").wrap("<strike>");
        $(".pic6").fadeOut("slow");
});

$(document).on('click', '*', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var tag = this.tagName;
        var index = $(tag).index(this); // doesn't work, as it gives the total no. elements

        $('#output').html(index);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom event:

```
$('.HiddenItem').css({display:'none'}).on('somethingElseClicked',function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

And then trigger it with the other click:

```
$('.ItemToTrigger').on('click',function(e){
    $('.HiddenItem').trigger('somethingElseClicked');
});
```

This is obviously supergeneralized, but it gives the framework necessary to trigger the event you want.

**EDIT**

Alright, so you will need to store each value for the clicks needed, as well as the total needed. I always prefer to use object-based variables rather than globals, so:

```
var click = {
    deal1:[0,2],
    deal2:[0,3],
    deal3:[0,5]
}
```

This creates arrays for each deal, the first being the number of clicks that have happened and the second being the total needed minus 1. You will then increment the "clicks that have happened" value, as well as prevent it from allowing double-clicks, by the JS described later. First, I recommend adding a generic class to all clickable items, as well as the deal items they are associated with, and verifying that way. The HTML:

```
<div class="picItem d1" data-fruit="apple">
<div class="picItem d2" data-fruit="pumpkin">
<div class="picItem d1" data-fruit="candle">
<div class="picItem d2" data-fruit="pear">
<div class="picItem d1 d2" data-fruit="mouse">
<div class="picItem d2" data-fruit="key">
```

And the JS I described:

```
$('.picItem').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $fruit = $this.data('fruit');

    $this.fadeOut('slow');

    if($this.hasClass('d1') && !$this.hasClass('clicked1')){
        if(click.deal1[0] < click.deal1[1]){
            click.deal1[0]++;
            $this.addClass('clicked1');
        } else {
            $('.deal1').trigger('showDeal');
        }
    }

    if($this.hasClass('d2') && !$this.hasClass('clicked2')){
        if(click.deal2[0] < click.deal2[1]){
            click.deal2[0]++;
            $this.addClass('clicked2');
        } else {
            $('.deal2').trigger('showDeal');
        }
    }

    if(!$this.hasClass('clicked3')){
        if(click.deal3[0] < click.deal3[1]){
            click.deal3[0]++;
            $this.addClass('clicked3');
        } else {
            $('.deal3').trigger('showDeal');
        }
    }

    $('.'+$fruit).wrap("<strike>");
});
```

The last `if` is for all elements clicked, hence not the need for adding a class and checking. The final piece grabs the associated data attribute and strikes it out.

Now you just trigger the event:

```
$('.deal1,.deal2,.deal3').on('showDeal',function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

This event will only be triggered when the appropriate number of clicks has been reached. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm4EV/5/) you gave me updated to show it is working as requested.

If you want to only allow one deal, you would just turn off the event after being triggered:

```
var $allDeals = $('.deal1,.deal2,.deal3');

$allDeals.on('showDeal',function(){
    $(this).show();

    if($(this).hasClass('deal3')){
        // this is to prevent deal 1 and deal 2 showing, since the criteria for them is also met
        $allDeals.not('.deal3').hide();
    }

    // this turns off all other deals
    $allDeals.off('showDeal');
    $('.picItem').off('click');
});
```

Not sure if you would need it or not, figured I would include it just in case. [Here is an updated jsFiddle to show that case working](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm4EV/6/).

Comment: *This is obviously supergeneralized, but it gives the framework necessary to trigger the event you want.* - You live up to your name :)

Comment: @NicholasV I don't believe in giving the fish, I believe in teaching how to fish. And hell, if he gave the appropriate items these specific classes it would work exactly as he wants. It would just be silly. :)

Comment: Thank you @PlantTheIdea - I appreciate your quick reply. This works for showing a div (.HiddenItem) when clicking on any item with class ".ItemToTrigger" , but I need to be able to click on multiple divs/images and only show the deal div when the user clicks on a specific few. That is what I am having trouble with. Here is my attempt with your answer (I could be doing it wrong! :P) http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/xg3qM/1/

Comment: (they have to click on all the images/divs in the specified group before the deal div shows not just one in the group)

Comment: edited my answer, hopefully it is more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer. When I test this in JSFIDDLE, the items are getting crossed out and fading but the deal is not showing. I don't understand the variable for clicks on the deal. Can you explain? Here is the JSFIDDLE updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/Fm4EV/4/

Comment: ah i made the mistake ... i did the length instead of length - 1. updated jsFiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/Fm4EV/5/ and i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. When I click on all the images all the deals show. How would I make only one deal div show at a time? separate the .on('showDeal', function () { ?

Comment: i just updated the answer to include some kind of logic, but you have consutructed a poorly-devised criteria. as you could guess, "clicking all of them" satisfies the criteria for the first two.

Comment: I did not explain enough, my apologies. Can only one deal be shown at a time but still allow other items to be clicked to find a different deal? I am marking this as the answer. Thank you for your help and explanation on the variable. I really appreciate the help as I learn this.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you can give your divs a corresponding data value to their p items for instance if you implement your div ( and all the other divs)

```
<div class="pic" data="pumpkin">
```

instead of

```
<div class="pic2">
```

You can write an almost oneliner with jquery

```
$('.pic').click(function () {
    $("#items p."+$(this).attr("data")).wrap("<strike>");
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

you can define your sets:
   set1 = ["apple","pumpkin"]
and after every click you can check clicked paragraphes with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var set1 = ["apple", "candle", "mouse"]


$('.deal1, .deal2, .deal3').hide();

$('.pic').click(function () {

    $("#items p." + $(this).attr("data")).wrap("<strike>").addClass("strike");
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    //test for set1
    set1Completed = true;
    for (i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
        if ($("p.strike." + set1[i]).length==0) {
            set1Completed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (set1Completed) {
        $('div.deal1').fadeIn(); // or fadeIn whatever u want
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow- thanks for the more concise way to click, strikeout and fade the image.

Comment: I am still having trouble with the second part though. Here is my JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/hHznq/2/

Comment: you just test the condition and do what you want. I edited the answer accordingly and corrected a typo

Comment: How do you define a set?

Comment: by writing var set1 = ["apple","pumpkin"] to outside, preferably under document.ready function

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me. I figured it was var (but I had too many equal signs in my first attempt) The deals are not showing even after defining the set. I am trying a set1 for apple, candle and mouse but when clicking on it it does not show the deal. here is updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudinne/hHznq/4/

Comment: you just have to take if set1Completed part inside of the .pic click function. Not outside of it. Sorry for my errs of paranthesis. I just edited my answer with a working code modified of your last fiddle.

Comment: Sorry this shows the deal if any of the items in the set are clicked. I would need it to only show the deal if ALL items in the set have been clicked.

Comment: jquery always returns an object so I corrected the if statement